# Send an outlook attachment from firefox,chrome and safari,is it anyway for such browsers except IE

Tags: javascript, outlook

I want to attach a file to outlook 2010 from IE,chrome ,and safari. I tried with IE they support for activexobject,I did that from IE. I came to know that no other browsers support this activexobject. I hope some body might know how to attach a file from other browsers to outlook 2010 (using jscript).please share if any possibility.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that. There a some browser plugins that let you use ActiveX controls, but I don't think anything is available that lets you use regular COM objects.

In theory, you can create a browser plugin that exposes COM objects as native JScript object (I did that for FF 3.6), but it is such a pain...